# @font-face não está funcionando no Chrome

Tags: css3, css-font-face

Recentemente um cliente subiu um site e a fonte que estava definida no font-face parou de funcionar. Em ambiente de testes, funcionava normalmente (o site estava hospedado em um site na nuvem, porém em um subdominio).

Curiosamente os links de font-face estão todos corretos, adaptei ao modelo fontspring bulletproff syntax e mesmo assim ainda não funcionou.

http://www.unirg.edu.br/

Olhando o código fonte você consegue ver o font-face incorporado inline no fim do código, coloquei o link externo porque estava executando alguns testes.

Alguem tem algum palpite do que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Já que vc pediu uma "dica" vou deixar como resposta o seu problema.

Vc está tendo uma restrição para indexar a `font` no documento devido ao [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS)

Muito provavelmente se vc colocar os arquivos das fonts tipo o `Panton-Bold.ttf` e `Panton-Bold.woff` no mesmo servidor onde está o site novo vc vai parar de ter esse erro e a `font` vai carregar. Repare que vc está no site `http://www.unirg.ed` buscando um arquivo de fonte que está em outro domínio `http://cannes.com.br` e muito provavelmente em outro servidor. Então por uma política de segurança o acesso é restringido. Pra evitar isso coloque os arquivos direto na pasta no unirg.ed no mesmo servidor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]